# Transferring recursive directory from local to remote

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

My requirement is to get the the logs from 'N' servers and FTP the logs into External hard disk which is connected to Remote computer with Recursive directory structure in the External Hard disk.

In Local computer, running the script which collects logs from 'N' Servers and store it in local directory and then FTP to Remote computer's External Hard disk.

For now, I can think of the following options.

1. Creating recursive directory structure locally and then FTP. I believe FTP does not support recursive directory structure transfer
2. copy the logs into External hardest, write a batch script to create directory structure and place the logs into respective directories.

Please let me know If I can implement this in any other alternative ways.

Comment: Use `rsync`; it already knows how to transfer directory structures.

Answer (score 1):

From my quick look of rsync,  I believe it's for Linux OS.
I need to FTP directory structure from from linux computer to windows computer.  Like winscp.